# Galera / InnoDB: how can "mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK': Lock wait timeout exceeded" happen?

Tags: innodb, mariadb, mysqldump, galera

Galera 3 node cluster with MariaDB 5.5

error

```
mysqldump: Couldn't execute 'FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK': Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction (1205)
```

backup command

```
mysqldump --max_allowed_packet=1G -u root -pdbpassword --opt --flush-logs --single-transaction  --all-databases | bzcat -zc > /var/lib/mysql/backup/fullbackup`date +%Y%m%d-%H%M%S`.sql.bz2
```

I found only [XtraBackup Failing with Lock wait timeout exceeded](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/percona-discussion/xqwCZuoP8x0) from Percona Discussion group

> The most likely explanation for this is that you have a long-running
>   statement (even a SELECT).
>
> innobackupex uses `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` to ensure exclusive
>   access to the non-transactional tables before it backs them up.  But
>   FTWRL requires that there be no statements running, and it will wait
>   until any current statements complete.  If you have a SELECT that is
>   running for 100 seconds for example, then FTWRL may give up before it
>   succeeds.  And therefore innobackupex won't be able to complete
>   backing up the non-transactional tables (e.g. mysql.*).
>
> The workaround if you are invoking innobackupex yourself is to use the
>   --no-lock option on the command-line.  But as far as I know, this is not possible when innobackupex is invoked as an SST method by PXC.

Only `mysql` db is `MyISAM` / no customer databases.

```
> SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES   WHERE engine = 'MyISAM';
+---------------+--------------+---------------------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| TABLE_CATALOG | TABLE_SCHEMA | TABLE_NAME                | TABLE_TYPE | ENGINE | VERSION | ROW_FORMAT | TABLE_ROWS | AVG_ROW_LENGTH | DATA_LENGTH | MAX_DATA_LENGTH    | INDEX_LENGTH | DATA_FREE | AUTO_INCREMENT | CREATE_TIME         | UPDATE_TIME         | CHECK_TIME          | TABLE_COLLATION   | CHECKSUM | CREATE_OPTIONS | TABLE_COMMENT                                     |
+---------------+--------------+---------------------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------+
| def           | mysql        | columns_priv              | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |              0 |           0 | 227994731135631359 |         4096 |         0 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-04-27 17:09:29 | NULL                | utf8_bin          |     NULL |                | Column privileges                                 |
| def           | mysql        | db                        | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Fixed      |        422 |            440 |      186560 | 123848989752688639 |        58368 |       880 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-05-03 00:16:26 | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | utf8_bin          |     NULL |                | Database privileges                               |
| def           | mysql        | event                     | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    |          0 |              0 |           0 |    281474976710655 |         2048 |         0 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-04-27 17:09:29 | NULL                | utf8_general_ci   |     NULL |                | Events                                            |
| def           | mysql        | func                      | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |              0 |           0 | 162974011515469823 |         1024 |         0 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-04-27 17:09:29 | NULL                | utf8_bin          |     NULL |                | User defined functions                            |
| def           | mysql        | help_category             | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    |         39 |             28 |        1092 |    281474976710655 |         3072 |         0 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-04-27 17:09:29 | NULL                | utf8_general_ci   |     NULL |                | help categories                                   |
| def           | mysql        | help_keyword              | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Fixed      |        464 |            197 |       91408 |  55450570411999231 |        16384 |         0 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-04-27 17:09:29 | NULL                | utf8_general_ci   |     NULL |                | help keywords                                     |
| def           | mysql        | help_relation             | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Fixed      |       1028 |              9 |        9252 |   2533274790395903 |        19456 |         0 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-04-27 17:09:29 | NULL                | utf8_general_ci   |     NULL |                | keyword-topic relation                            |
| def           | mysql        | help_topic                | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    |        508 |            886 |      450388 |    281474976710655 |        20480 |         0 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-04-27 17:09:29 | NULL                | utf8_general_ci   |     NULL |                | help topics                                       |
| def           | mysql        | host                      | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |              0 |           0 | 110056715893866495 |         2048 |         0 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-04-27 17:09:29 | NULL                | utf8_bin          |     NULL |                | Host privileges;  Merged with database privileges |
| def           | mysql        | ndb_binlog_index          | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    |          0 |              0 |           0 |    281474976710655 |         1024 |         0 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-04-27 17:09:29 | NULL                | latin1_swedish_ci |     NULL |                |                                                   |
| def           | mysql        | plugin                    | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    |          1 |             32 |          32 |    281474976710655 |         2048 |         0 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-04-27 17:09:29 | NULL                | utf8_general_ci   |     NULL |                | MySQL plugins                                     |
| def           | mysql        | proc                      | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    |          3 |           1208 |        3624 |    281474976710655 |         4096 |         0 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-04-27 17:09:29 | NULL                | utf8_general_ci   |     NULL |                | Stored Procedures                                 |
| def           | mysql        | procs_priv                | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |              0 |           0 | 239253730204057599 |         4096 |         0 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-04-27 17:09:29 | NULL                | utf8_bin          |     NULL |                | Procedure privileges                              |
| def           | mysql        | proxies_priv              | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Fixed      |          1 |            693 |        1386 | 195062158860484607 |         5120 |       693 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-04-27 17:09:29 | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | utf8_bin          |     NULL |                | User proxy privileges                             |
| def           | mysql        | servers                   | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |              0 |           0 | 433752939111120895 |         1024 |         0 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-04-27 17:09:29 | NULL                | utf8_general_ci   |     NULL |                | MySQL Foreign Servers table                       |
| def           | mysql        | tables_priv               | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |              0 |           0 | 239535205180768255 |         4096 |         0 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-04-27 17:09:29 | NULL                | utf8_bin          |     NULL |                | Table privileges                                  |
| def           | mysql        | time_zone                 | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |              0 |           0 |   1970324836974591 |         1024 |         0 |              1 | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-04-27 17:09:29 | NULL                | utf8_general_ci   |     NULL |                | Time zones                                        |
| def           | mysql        | time_zone_leap_second     | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |              0 |           0 |   3659174697238527 |         1024 |         0 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-04-27 17:09:29 | NULL                | utf8_general_ci   |     NULL |                | Leap seconds information for time zones           |
| def           | mysql        | time_zone_name            | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |              0 |           0 |  55450570411999231 |         1024 |         0 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-04-27 17:09:29 | NULL                | utf8_general_ci   |     NULL |                | Time zone names                                   |
| def           | mysql        | time_zone_transition      | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |              0 |           0 |   4785074604081151 |         1024 |         0 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-04-27 17:09:29 | NULL                | utf8_general_ci   |     NULL |                | Time zone transitions                             |
| def           | mysql        | time_zone_transition_type | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Fixed      |          0 |              0 |           0 |  10696049115004927 |         1024 |         0 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-04-27 17:09:29 | NULL                | utf8_general_ci   |     NULL |                | Time zone transition types                        |
| def           | mysql        | user                      | BASE TABLE | MyISAM |      10 | Dynamic    |        424 |            120 |       51132 |    281474976710655 |        17408 |       240 |           NULL | 2016-04-06 17:50:04 | 2017-05-03 00:16:26 | NULL                | utf8_bin          |     NULL |                | Users and global privileges                       |
+---------------+--------------+---------------------------+------------+--------+---------+------------+------------+----------------+-------------+--------------------+--------------+-----------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------------+-------------------+----------+----------------+---------------------------------------------------+
22 rows in set, 3 warnings (21.77 sec)
```

why `mysqldump` uses `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK`? Howto debug this error?

Answer (score 2):

For mysqldump, `FLUSH TABLES WITH READ LOCK` is only issue with `--master-data`, or `--flush-logs` together with `--single-transaction`.

To debug, simply turn on general query log (`general_log=1`) and you should see the corresponding line where MySQL executes this statement.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using single transaction and flush logs, you can pass `--master-data=2` 
This will help you to get the correct table contents and `binary log and position`. Once the dump is completed you can see the bin log file name and its position inside the dump.